# Problem with ssh -Y

Tags: front-end, remote-access

I ssh -Y to the remote Linux machine and run "nohup mathematica&" and use the frontend graphically for a long time. Then, it disconnected. I login back and see that the Mathematica and WolframKernel's are still running. Can I still get the .nb file saved?